# Change browser search provider programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to open an url in Edge, using following command:

```
sURL = "http://maps.google.it/maps?hl=it&q=VIA+TRENTO%00+26+GALLIPOLI+LE&f=q&sampleq=1&ie=UTF8&iwloc=A";

var pr = New Process;
var prInfo = New ProcessStartInfo;

prInfo.FileName = $"microsoft-edge:{sURL}";
prInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
pr.StartInfo = prInfo;
pr.Start();
```

then Microsoft Edge is started correctly but it doesn't open the given URL.
If I try to set manually the Google search provider, the page is opened correctly.
Does it possible to change programmatically the search provider?
Otherwise, is there another way to open an address using Google Maps in Edge?

Comment: What is the value of sURL before the first line? 
What happens, when you remove sURL from the string?

Comment: @Kronos, I used the default provider Bing, but based on my test, it works well for me. I can open the Google Maps well.

Comment: I've found that is an encoding issue. If I remove the characters '%00' from url, the page is opened correctly.